# creating transactionmanager and entity manager via configuration class

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i am relatively new to spring and want to implement the spring jpa with mysql. below mentioned is my configurations...

```
<beans ...
<context:component-scan base-package="com.pg" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<tx:annotation-driven/>

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.pg.dao" /> ...
```

My configuation class to create the datasource, transactionmanager and entitymanager is listed below.

```
package com.pg.conf;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;

import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.FactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

@Configuration
public class JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource datasource = new BasicDataSource();
        datasource.setDriverClassName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getName());
        datasource.setUrl("jdbc:mydql://localhost:3306/pg1");
        datasource.setUsername("root");
        datasource.setPassword("root");
        return datasource;
    }

    @Bean
    public **FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory>** entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean containerEntityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adaptor = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(adaptor);
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.pg.entity");
        Properties props = new Properties();        
        props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        containerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(props);
        return containerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        **jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());**
        return transactionManager();
    }

}
```

i have error on the line **jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());**

i think the returntype of the entitymanager method is not correct... even though it does not show error....

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Start with reading the Spring reference guide and read about [`FactoryBean`s](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension-factorybean).

Then change your code accordingly.

```
@Bean
public TransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory){
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

Comment: Actually `FactoryBean` + JavaConfig has a proxy issue and it isn't recommended to use `getObject()` dirrectly at all, especially on bean configuration phase. As a trick: use the result of `FactoryBean` as a bean-method parameter and autowire processor does the stuff for you.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. i created transaction manager in the spring beans xml file and things are working fine at present.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
```

with

```
jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory((EntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory());
```